# Text deletion between patterns across multiple lines with respect to text inside pattern

Tags: linux, bash, sed, perl, awk

I have a block of text I need to delete, however, only if it contains specific text inside the block:

```
...
<script language="JavaScript">
    var somethingA = 0;
    var somethingB = 0;
    var somethingC = 0;
    // do some stuff
</script>

<script language="JavaScript">
    var somethingA = 0;
    var somethingC = 0;
    var somethingD = 0;
    // do some stuff
</script>
....
```

I want to remove only the `<script>` block that has `var somethingB` in it.  There could be any number of `<script>` blocks in the file in any position.

I was hoping to use sed doing something like:

```
sed 's/<script/,/<\/script>/ D'
```

However, I can't figure out how to only delete the block with `var somethingB` in it.

PS:  I could also use perl or awk.  I would rather use sed for consistency sake, but if it is easier in perl and/or awk I would switch gears pretty quick at this point.  Thanks!

Comment: The canonical ["don't parse html with regex"](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/7552) answer...

Comment: @glennjackman Let's pretend it's not HTML ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If a partial solution in `vim` is acceptable:

```
:%s/<script [^<]*\(\n[^<]*\)*somethingB.*\(\n[^<]*\)*<\/script>//g
```

but it won't work if there are other tags inside the `<script>` ones, because using `[^<]`, the pattern may not contain `<`.

Answer (score 0):

I do not have a simple solution.  Actually it uses awk to code the needed algorithm in the C-like language of awk.  Assuming the text to filter is in a file called 'filename':

```
awk 'BEGIN { curr=0 } \
     /<script .*>/ { in_block=1; del_block=0 } \
     /<\/script>/ { in_block=0; blockend=1 } \
     /var[[:space:]]+somethingB/ { if (in_block==1) \
                                     { del_block=1 } } \
    { if (in_block==0) \
        { if (blockend==0) \
            # Neither in a block nor block end reached.
            # Just print the line
            { print } \
          else \
            { # End of a block reached. Do block end handling
              # just this one time. Block end flag off
              blockend=0
              if (del_block==1) \
                { # delete the block. Just throw away the lines
                  # in the lines array
                  curr=0 } \
              else \
                { # End of block and no delete. Print it out
                  for (i=0; i<curr; i++) \
                    { print line[i] }
                    print   # Print the </script> line
                      # use line-array for the next block
                      curr=0 \
                } \
            } \
        } \
      else \
        { # In a block. Save the current line for later
          line[curr]=$0
          curr++ } \
    }' filename
```

The pattern for `</script>` (the end marker of a block) is a bit simple.  It expects that it is exactly written like that without any spaces.  If it can contain whitespaces, you may want to write it like this:

```
/<[[:space:]]*\/script[[:space:]]*>/
```

The pattern for `var somethingB` is `var` - one or more white spaces - `somethingB`, which is probably what you are searching for.  If you want it fixed to exactly one space between `var` and `somethingB` it's simpler: `/var somethingB/`

Answer (score 0):

This should be doable in `sed` directly. As I'm no `sed` wizard, I need two runs.

1. In the first run we prepare the file to ensure that the `<script>...</script>` blocks are surronded with blank lines:

   ```
   sed -e '/<script/i\ ' -e '/script>/a\ ' code.js
   ```

   It's no rocket-science: `i` *inserts* a line *before* the line matching a pattern,  `a` accordingly *appends* a line *after* the line matching a pattern. In both cases the line consists of a single blank only.

   This is needed that `sed` detects every block separately, i.e. *non-greedily* in the second step).
2. The second run kills the blocks with `var somethingB` in it:

   ```
   sed '/<script/,/script>/{H;d;};x;/var somethingB/d'
   ```

   - `/<script/,/script>/{H;d;}` moves a block into sed's holding space (`H` appends to holding space, `d` deletes from pattern space)
   - `x` exchanges the holding space with the pattern space
   - if pattern `/var somethingB/` matches delete (`d`) the pattern space, which holds  the complete `<script>` block.
   - finally `sed` implicitly prints the pattern space.

     *My reference here was the [Unix Sed Tutorial](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/12/unix-sed-tutorial-7-examples-for-sed-hold-and-pattern-buffer-operations/).*
3. So, in one command line with a nice pipe:

   ```
   sed -e '/<script/i\ ' -e '/script>/a\ ' code.js | sed '/<script/,/script>/{H;d;};x;/var somethingB/d'
   ```

   If you want to, use a third `sed` instance to get rid of the additional empty lines:

   ```
   sed '/^ $/d'
   ```

Comment: @Matt: Can you please give a feedback if you are satisfied with my sed approach?!

Comment: This solution is awesome!  For some reason I missed it in my Inbox and never saw it until now.  The only downside is it removes the last line in the file.  But otherwise it works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if this is the most efficient way, but I managed to write this purely in a `sed` one-liner. Assuming your block of text is in `file.txt`:

```
tac file.txt | sed '/var somethingB/,/<script/{/var somethingB/p;d;}' | tac | sed '/var somethingB/,/<\/script>/d'
```

Or you can even be a bit more restrictive and do:

```
tac file.txt | sed '/var somethingB = /,/^<script /{/var somethingB = /p;d;}' | tac | sed '/var somethingB = /,/^<\/script>$/d'
```

This is how it works:

1. Read the file in reverse order: `tac file.txt`
2. In the first run, remove the lines between pattern ("var somethingB") and beginning of the block ("<script") –remember reading the file in reverse order–. But exclude the line which contains "var somethingB" (we'll need it for the second run): `sed '/var somethingB/,/<script/{/var somethingB/p;d;}'`
3. Read the file in reverse again (now we're reading in normal order): `tac`
4. In the second run, remove the lines between pattern ("var somethingB") and the end of the block (""): `sed '/var somethingB/,/<\/script>/d'`. Notice that we need to escape character / with a .